# djinni - pointers and circular references between C++ and swift/objective C/java

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, swift, djinni

I have two djinni interfaces, one to be implemented in Swift/objective C/java `SwiftObj` and one to be implemented in C++ `CPPObj`.

```
SwiftObj = interface +o +j {
    someSwiftMethod();
}

CPPObj = interface +c {
    static create(swiftObj: SwiftObj): CPPObj;
    someCPPMethod();
}
```

They both have a pointer to each other, so the `SwiftObj` will be able to call `someCPPMethod()` of the `CPPObj` and viceversa: `CPPObj` will be able to call `someSwiftMethod()` from the `SwiftObj`:

**In swift:**

- the class variable: `var myCPPObj: SwiftObj!`
- the creation: `myCPPObj = MyCPPObj.create(self)`
- the usage: `myCPPObj.someCPPMethod()`

**In c++:**

- the class variable: `shared_ptr<SwiftObj> mySwiftObj_;`
- the usage: `mySwiftObj_->someSwiftMethod();`

So the question here is, these objects are not getting garbage collected due to the circular reference (I tried and removed the circular reference and they got GCed).

But then I tried setting one of those pointers as weak. In C++: `weak_ptr<SwiftObj> mySwiftObj_;` ... but this made the `mySwiftObj_` be GCed instantly, even while it actually still exists in swift. Same thing happened when I set the swift pointer as weak and the C++ as strong.

So how can I deal with this situation? (other than manually setting one of those pointers as null). Any insights on how the pointers actually work in djinni?

Thanks!

Comment: The matter isn't how they work in djinni, djinni has no pointers at all. Your problem is that probably you don't know how smart pointers work in C++. Am I right?

Comment: No. If it were all in C++ , setting A ---strong---> B and setting B ---weak--> A would solve the circular pointer problem. But since djinni is in the middle, if I have a weak pointer it gets GCed instantly.

Comment: djinni doesn't return you weak pointers, it's you that assign the shared it returns to a weak one. You know?

Comment: I know and I tried to do that already. read the post.

Comment: I've read the post and I was commenting it indeed. Just pointing out the fact that you aren't using properly smart pointers.

Comment: I don't think you're doing it wrong.  Weak-ref semantics across languages are a legitimately hard problem.  See my more detailed answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no sort of weak reference/pointer which can understand ownership across languages and Djinni doesn't attempt to add one.  The available weak semantics in C++ and Swift only know about references within the same language, which is why you see the instant GC behavior.  It's the Djinni-generated proxy object which is being weakly held, and becomes unused, but once the proxy goes away, it releases the real object.

I think the simplest approach would be to split the Swift object into two objects, let's call them Owner and Listener.  In your example only Listener needs to be a Djinni object, and implement `someSwiftMethod()`.  Maybe you have other reasons for Owner to be a Djinni interface too.  Set up your ownership graph as follows.  Forgive the ASCII art: Swift is on the left, C++ on the right.

```
                  <- Swift|C++ ->

  SwiftOwner ------------------------> CppObj
    ^    |                               |
    |    |                               |
 (weak)  |                               |
    |    v                               |
  SwiftListener <------------------------+
```

In this scenario, the circularity and weak-refs are all limited to Swift, so will work as you expect, and `SwiftListener` can forward along methods to `SwiftOwner` as necessary.  This model is optimized for the case where the external usage of these objects is coming from Swift.  Such users should hold a reference to `SwiftOwner`.  If your primary usage is in C++ you could reverse the picture, or you could have the external C++ objects hold a strong reference to SwiftOwner.  Either way, SwiftOwner has no (strong) circular references to it, and once it's released, the other two objects will be released too.